# Value Objects in PHP

Tags: php, oop

How do I create a PHP class that allows no dynamic properties?

```
class User
{
  public $username;
  public $password;
}

$user = new User;
$user->username = "bill.gates";

// This is a dynamic property and I need setting it to be considered illegal.
$user->something = 123;
```

Comment: (+1) Dynamic properties may be useful for some developers, but, personally I prefer standard properties with internal variable fields, with getters & setters methods, which provide more control over properties...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to the rescue:

```
class User
{
  public $username;
  public $password;

  public function __set($key, $value) {
    throw new Exception('illegal'); // or just trigger_error()
  }
}
```

Comment: This will also forbid the developer to assign values to valid, non-dynamic properties, right?

Comment: @leon: No, `__set` is only called [when trying to write to inaccessible properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members). Existing visible properties don't trigger it.

Comment: @leon: No, "`__set()` is run when writing data to inaccessible properties". Even if the property was inaccessible you could easily throw some function calls to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [constraining php dynamic properties](http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/02/constraining-php-dynamic-properties/). The idea is to specify which properties do exist and can be modified on an array, and then validate whether the property being updated (as in Alix's answer, example expanded below) is part of that permission list.

```
class User
{
    public $username;
    public $password;

    private $non_dynamic_props = array('username','password');

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if($this->check_legal_assignment($key))
            $this->$$key = $value;
        else
            throw new Exception('illegal'); // or just trigger_error()
    }

    private function check_legal_assignment($prop){
        return in_array($prop, $this->non_dynamic_props);
    }
}
```